# Can't edit value in datatable using OnRowEdit in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I've followed PrimeFaces showcases to use row editing datatable but i can't see why it's not updating data.

here's my datatable:

```
<p:dataTable id="tab" var="art" value="#{myMB.allArticles}" editable="true" style="margin-bottom:20px">
   <f:facet name="header">

   </f:facet>

   <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{myMB.onRowEdit}" update=":form:msgs" />
   <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{myMB.onRowCancel}" update=":form:msgs" />

   <p:column headerText="Name ">
       <p:cellEditor>
           <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{art.name}" /></f:facet>
           <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{art.name}"  style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
       </p:cellEditor>
   </p:column>

   <p:column headerText="Budget">
       <p:cellEditor>
           <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{art.budget}" /></f:facet>
           <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{art.budget}" style="width:100%" label="Budget"/></f:facet>
       </p:cellEditor>
   </p:column>
   <p:column style="width:32px">

       <p:rowEditor  />
   </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
```

and in the bean:

```
public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event ) {

    Article f =  (Article) event.getObject();

    formationFacade.update(f);
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Article Edited", ((Article) event.getObject()).getName());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

I ve seen this : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769794/primefaces-datatableedit-row-hibernate-mysqldatabase) but it doesn't work for me I get the old value after editing and I have no change in may database  .. can someone help me please?

Comment: The code seems right, did you check the value of `Article f`? maybe do you have an error on `formationFacade.update(f);` code line?

Comment: thanks @giaffa86 for your reply .. when I put a **System.out.println("budget de la formation :: : "+f.getBudget()); ** I get the old value and I don't think that the error is in the update method because it work fine if I don't use onRowEdit ..I m lost because I cant see where is my problem

Comment: Ok. Did you wrap your dataTable inside to `h:form`? This is the only problem that I see. You called your datatable "form", probably you wrong on this. Each input component must be inside a form

Comment: Yes my dataTable is inside the `h:form`...even if I write a new value in the inputText it doesn't change anything..in fact the only difference I have from the primefaces showcases is that my dataTable is fill with a list of value from database and not a static one .. I don't know if I should do any change in this method ?

Comment: If `allArticles` is a properly setted as bean property, there aren't differences between static filling and dynamic filling.

Comment: Try to put just `:form` on update attribute of rowEdit tag.

Comment: I've just tried primefaces example showcase and it works well on Primefaces 5.1, JSF Mojarra 2.2.7 . If do you change datamodel something good happens? Maybe you have some faces config property that made a conflict with normal behaviour. Can you also test primefaces showcase example?

Comment: @giaffa86 I just tried primefaces example showcase and also it work fine .. I actually use primefaces 5.0 ,JSF2.2 with Jboss 7.

Comment: Really weird, try to start from primefaces example and recreate your situation changing only the datamodel and `OnRowEdit` method.

Comment: its exactly what I ve did .. I don't know if I should add somthing else in addition to `em.merge` in my update method O.o ?

Comment: I don't know what your update method do. But it's not important if `f` doesn't have updated values (before to pass it to update method).

Answer (score 0):

There's one thing that is strange/wrong, that may or may not be the cause of your issues, but I would recommend fixing. From this  `update=":form:msgs"`  I assume that you have an enclosing tags like  `<h:form id="form"><p:growl id="msgs"`. On the other hand you repeat the `id="form"` inside `<p:dataTable id="form"`. Repeating the id is surely wrong, but I'm not sure if its the cause of your issue

Comment: thaanks for your unswer @Master Slave yes I have an `<h:form id="form"><p:growl id="msgs" `and I just change the id of the datatable thanks for your remarque but this is not the cause of my problem because I still cant get the new value

Comment: yeps, not suprised though, still its the only wrong thing immediately spottable, sorry it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

first, you have to provide the `EditMode` parameter with the value of

```
CellEdit
```

or `RowEdit` as your case.

second, you can do edit like this without event if you want a simple way to edit data table is

```
modifyYourModel(Model x){
// call your function to modify 
}
```

and in the data table, you can do that

```
<p:dataTable id="tab" var="art" value="#{myMB.allArticles}" editable="true" EditMode="rowEdit" style="margin-bottom:20px">
   <f:facet name="header">

   </f:facet>

   <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{myMB.modifyYourModel(art)}" update=":form:msgs" />
   <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{myMB.onRowCancel}" update=":form:msgs" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your IDs instead of :form, :msgs.

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{myMB.onRowEdit}" update="messages tab" />
<p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{myMB.onRowCancel}" update="messages tab" />
```

Also you have to update list "allArticles" by edited object.

Comment: :form:msgs IS an id... It is the full absolute client id which is needed if you go to the up in the component tree to update something. So that part in the question is good and hence that part of your answer is sort of not.

Comment: But that does not works for me (Primefaces 7.0). I tried it now and answer sounds:
"javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component for expression ":form:msgs" referenced from"datatable_id"

Comment: Yes, but than you don't have components in your page with id's that result in this clientId. And that is not uncommon, everybody picks his or hers own id's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156